# Why won't the turtle draw anything?

Tags: python-3.x, 3d, turtle-graphics, voxel

I was trying to make a voxel engine using the turtle library in python, but when I run it, nothing happens. I've tested it and altered most of what I thought the problem was, but I still can't figure it out.

I've tryed altering the position of the player, changing the way it draws the point, And the rotation of the player's view. I'm at my last straw and this is my only hope.

```
import turtle as t
import random as r
import math as m

#Voxel positions
xcord = 1
ycord = 1
zcord = -50

#Player position
camx = 0
camy = 0
camz = 0

#Player Rotation
rotx = 90
roty = -180

#Trig Values
sinx = 0
cosx = 0
siny = 0
cosy = 0

#Field of View
FOV = 60

#Distance and Pen Size
Dist = 0
quality = 2


def trig_vals():
    sinx = m.sin(rotx)
    cosx = m.cos(rotx)
    siny = m.sin(roty)
    cosy = m.cos(roty)


def set_point(x, y, z):
    xcord = x
    ycord = y
    zcord = z


def onscreen_point(x, y):
    xcord = x
    ycord = y


def calc_rotation(x, y, z):
    set_point(x - camx, y - camy, z - camz)
    set_point((zcord * siny) + (xcord * cosy), ycord,(zcord * cosy) - (xcord * siny))
    set_point(xcord, (zcord * cosx) - (ycord * sinx),(zcord * sinx) + (ycord * cosx))


def Draw_Point(x, y, z, c):
    calc_rotation(x, y, z)
    onscreen_point((200 - FOV) * (xcord / zcord),(200 - FOV) * (ycord / zcord))
    t.goto(xcord, ycord)
    dist = (m.sqrt((zcord * zcord) + (zcord * zcord)) / 15)
    if not (((abs(xcord) > 240) or (abs(ycord) > 180)) or dist > 99):
        t.pencolor(c)

        #Brightness
        dist = (quality * 1) * (200 - FOV)
        t.pensize(dist)
        t.pendown()
        t.penup()


def setup():
  t.hideturtle()
  t.Screen().setup(480,360)
  t.Screen().bgcolor("black")
  trig_vals()


#Test Run
while True:
    setup()
    Draw_Point(1, 50, 50, "white")
```

Basically what I have now, what is it missing that is causing the turtle to not draw>

Comment: Turtle is probably the wrong tool for making a voxel engine. To debug this, ensure you're actually drawing something when you `pendown()` then `penup()` right afterwards without anything in between. Minimize the problem, stripping out the unnecessary stuff to figure out the mistake.

Comment: If you want to make a voxel engine, you'll have a much easier time using PySimpleGUI (check out the graph element), instead of using turtle.

Comment: Thank you both, but I am trying to challenge myself by using turtle. I have used other resources before to make 3D engines, but I want to break the limits of turtle.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe you wrote this much code without any testing to see if you were on the right track.  Specific problems: without a `global` statement, these three routines are no-ops:

```
def trig_vals():
    sinx = m.sin(rotx)
    cosx = m.cos(rotx)
    siny = m.sin(roty)
    cosy = m.cos(roty)

def set_point(x, y, z):
    xcord = x
    ycord = y
    zcord = z

def onscreen_point(x, y):
    xcord = x
    ycord = y
```

The second setting of `dist` tosses the earlier calculation of `dist`:

```
    dist = (m.sqrt((zcord * zcord) + (zcord * zcord)) / 15)
    if not (((abs(xcord) > 240) or (abs(ycord) > 180)) or dist > 99):
        t.pencolor(c)

        #Brightness
        dist = (quality * 1) * (200 - FOV)
        t.pensize(dist)
```

3/4 of what your `setup()` routine sets up doesn't need to be in an infinite loop.  You have both `dist` and `Dist` variables, one of which isn't used.  I've reworked your code below to get it to do *something* that draws with depth perspective:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import sin, cos, sqrt

# Voxel positions
xcord = 1
ycord = 1
zcord = -50

# Player position
camx = 0
camy = 0
camz = 0

# Player Rotation
rotx = 90
roty = -180

# Trig Values
sinx = sin(rotx)
cosx = cos(rotx)
siny = sin(roty)
cosy = cos(roty)

# Field of View
FOV = 60

# Distance and Pen Size
Dist = 0  # how is this related to `dist`?
quality = 2

def trig_vals():
    global sinx, cosx, siny, cosy

    sinx = sin(rotx)
    cosx = cos(rotx)
    siny = sin(roty)
    cosy = cos(roty)

def set_point(x, y, z):
    global xcord, ycord, zcord

    xcord = x
    ycord = y
    zcord = z

def onscreen_point(x, y):
    global xcord, ycord

    xcord = x
    ycord = y

def calc_rotation(x, y, z):
    trig_vals()
    set_point(x - camx, y - camy, z - camz)
    set_point((zcord * siny) + (xcord * cosy), ycord, (zcord * cosy) - (xcord * siny))
    set_point(xcord, (zcord * cosx) - (ycord * sinx), (zcord * sinx) + (ycord * cosx))

def Draw_Point(x, y, z, c):
    calc_rotation(x, y, z)
    onscreen_point((200 - FOV) * (xcord / zcord), (200 - FOV) * (ycord / zcord))
    turtle.goto(xcord, ycord)
    dist = sqrt((zcord * zcord) + (zcord * zcord)) / 15

    if not (((abs(xcord) > 240) or (abs(ycord) > 180)) or dist > 99):
        turtle.pencolor(c)

        # Brightness
        # this tosses earlier `dist` calculation based on zcord!
        # dist = (quality * 1) * (200 - FOV)
        turtle.dot(100 / dist)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(480, 360)
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

Draw_Point(50, 50, 10, 'white')
Draw_Point(50, 150, 100, 'red')

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]